# Case Conversion GraphDB spif:titleCase unexpected behaviour

Tags: sparql, graphdb

I am working to achieve title case conversion and using the spif:titleCase() function implementation in GraphDB.

**Expected result**: `taxon concept label` becomes `Taxon Concept Label`

**Received result**: `taxon concept label` becomes `TAXON CONCEPT LABEL`

I have made an example at the link [here](http://graph.openbiodiv.net/sparql?name=&infer=true&sameAs=true&query=PREFIX%20spif%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fspinrdf.org%2Fspif%23%3E%0APREFIX%20skos%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2004%2F02%2Fskos%2Fcore%23%3E%0APREFIX%20rdfs%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23%3E%0Aselect%20*%0A%0A%20%20WHERE%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%3Fs%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%3Flabel%0A%20%20%20%20BIND%20(lcase(str(%3Flabel))%20as%20%3Flcase)%0A%20%20%20%20BIND(spif%3AtitleCase(str(%3Flcase))%20as%20%3Ftcase)%0A%20%20%20%20%23BIND%20(replace(lcase(%3Flabel)%2C%20%22(%5C%5Cb%5Ba-z%5D(%3F!%5C%5Cs))%22%2C%20ucase(str(%22%241%22%20))%20)%20as%20%3Ftcase)%0A%0A%7D%20limit%2010) to verify what I have found.

Explaining this behaviour goes beyond my comprehension, maybe someone here can tell why this happen and how to rectify it to work as expected?

Comment: Looks like a bug to me. Maybe you should report that. I get the same unexpected result with this simple query: `PREFIX spif: <http://spinrdf.org/spif#>

SELECT * 
WHERE { 
    BIND("test case" AS ?string)
    BIND(spif:titleCase(?string) AS ?result)
}
`

Comment: I am hoping the Ontotext folks are reading this. I haven't found an alternative channel to report the problem. Would be cool if they can fix it.